# Google Data Studio Report Displaying Incorrect Values From Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a report in Google Data Studio, and a Google Sheet data source that has been configured to it. However I have noticed that at times the values are off by a couple numbers or the values are totally random (not even present in the spreadsheet connected). The values in the spreadsheet are standard types: integers, strings or dates. If anyone knows why this occurs or how to fix it, input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend re-reviewing your Data Source settings within Google Data Studio to ensure all fields are correctly set to the appropriate type.

In Data Studio: `Resource > Manage Added Data Source > Actions > Edit`:

- Review the **"Type"** column.
- Review the **"Default Aggregation"** column.
- [Related Google Docs](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6402048/model-your-data#dimensions-and-metrics-in-your-data-source)

If all of your fields are correctly set, you should also review individual **"Type"** settings for each of your charts dimensions and metrics.

1. Select a Chart
2. Hover Cursor on Dimension or Metric Icon in the Settings
3. Click on the Pencil
4. Review **"Type"** Settings

If you are still seeing the issues, I'd recommend setting up a Table Chart and reviewing your import data line-by-line for incorrect data. There might be an underlying issue with how Google Data Studio is reading data from your GoogleSheet.